# Wix toolset Bundle Chain installation global condition

Tags: wix, windows-installer

**CONTEXT:** I created a Bootstrapper installer in order to install, if needed, the .net framework 4.8. together with the setup program I want to deliver with it.

Up to here all works nice: my program gets installed always and the .net just if needed.

The thing is that I need to add some more checks to this installer, for example check for a registry key (if another program proper version is installed) and if this does not meet the condition, then the complete installation should be aborted, nothing should be installed.

**PROBLEM:** the `InstallCondition` I have added affects just the `MsiPackage` but the rest of the installation seems to be considered as totally fine and installation finishes successfully, here the interesting part of code:

```
<util:RegistrySearch Id="OtherProgramVersionId" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\XXX\Install::Version" Variable="OtherProgramVersion"/>

<Chain>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx48Redist" />
  <MsiPackage 
    Id="MySuperProgram.Setup" 
    SourceFile="$(var.MySuperProgram.Setup.TargetPath)"
    InstallCondition="OtherProgramVersion >= v10.0"/>
</Chain>
```

As said before, even the registry key is not found or it does not fulfill the condition, the installation seems to continue "successfully" and I get it in the ControlPanel->Programs as installed... but the main .msi was not really installed! (checking the destination folder, it's empty)

**QUESTION:** How can I add a global condition in order to stop completely any installation at all and show the user a message with the condition not fulfilled? If possible with a standard dialog.

I have seen (and I am still experiencing) with conditions, but seems they affect just one of the items in the chain... or they seem to break the installation somehow, I have tried adding to the .msi setup creation, file Product.wxs, the condition in order to abort this installation, but when installing I get this not passed condition as a setup error, seems the exit is not clean at all... even able to see the log where I see something like this:

> Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `WixStandardBootstrapperApplication`, you can use [`bal:Condition`](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/bal/condition.html) to define bundle-level conditions. The WiX documentation has a sample: https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/block_stdba_install_on_reg.html

Comment: It works, so it prevents the setup of being installed, even the dialog shown seems to point that something else happened, but that's another topic, I guess I need to define the UIDialog somehow... too advanced and complex for now!